# Структуры данных для хранения и работы с матрицами

Tags: структуры-данных, массивы, c, структуры, c++

Доброго времени суток!
Есть матрица, у которой надо периодически удалять то столбец целиком, то строку.
Вариант "вектор векторов" дает возможность удалять либо строки, либо столбцы.
Если нужно и так и так, то приходится для чего-то одного(например, удаление строк) выбирать удаление вектора, а для другого(удаление столбцов) - создавать новую матрицу.
Собственно вопрос: существуют ли какие-то уже готовые структуры, с которыми можно осуществлять подобные операции над матрицами?
Собственно, принимаются любые варианты, лишь бы это было быстро и не тратило много памяти.
Поиск в гугле по ключевым словам, увы, ни к чему толковому не привел.
Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: @miramentis, почему Вы считаете, что при удалении столбца в методе "вектор векторов" (т.е. вектор указателей на вектора, каждый из которых представляет строку) требуется создание новой матрицы?

Операция будет проводиться "по месту" (без переписывания данных в новую память). Конечно, время удаления столбца квадратично от размера матрицы ("хвост" каждой строки придется сдвигать), но IMHO эта операция *по сравнению с доступом* к i,j-м элементам в целом алгоритме наверняка редка.

А вот реализация тривиальна (программа останется понятной).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно не удалять фактически элементы, а просто хранить индексы удаленных столбцов и строк. Пользователю класса предоставлять интерфейс, который будет мимикрировать под матрицу меньшего размера.

В качестве структуры данных для хранения удаленных индексов и бысрого нахождения соответствия нового индекса к исходному можно использовать немного модифицированное дерево отрезков поверх массива, хранящего 0 или 1, в зависимости от того удален элемент или нет. Подробнее можно прочитать [в статье](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree), пункт "Поиск префикса массива с заданной суммой".

Особенности (`N` - линейный размер исходной матрицы, `n` -- новой):

- Произвольный доступ за `O(log(N))`, вместо `O(1)`.
- Итерация по строке/столбцу стоит `O(N)`, вместо `O(n)`. Но кажется, что итерирование по столбцу, если строки хранятся в векторах, сильно не пострадает.
- Удаление строки или столбца можно делать за `O(log(N))`.
- Оверхед по памяти `O(N)`, что не сильно влияет на общий размер `O(N^2)`.
- Можно использовать для быстрого конструирования подматрицы исходной матрицы. Это может  пригодиться, если мы захотим выполнить какой-то алгоритм над подматрицей, например верхней правой четвертью.
- Можно за лагарифм возвращать строки и столбцы обратно.

---

**UPD** Оказалось, что обход строки и столбца можно делать за `O(n)`, если я конечно правильно оценил асимптотику. Алгоритм простой: обходим листья дерева отрезков, в которых записана 1. При этом не заходим в поддеревья, у которых в корне записан 0, так как у них не может быть ненулевых листьев. Набросал демострационную программку на Python:

```
import random
import sys

def build(arr, tree, v, l, r):
  if l == r:
    tree[v] = arr[l]
    return
  c = (l + r) / 2
  build(arr, tree, v * 2, l, c)
  build(arr, tree, v * 2 + 1, c + 1, r)
  tree[v] = tree[v * 2] + tree[v * 2 + 1]

def traverse(tree, v, l, r, counter=[0]):
  counter[0] += 1
  if l == r:
    yield l
    return
  c = (l + r) / 2
  if tree[v * 2]:
    for i in traverse(tree, v * 2, l, c, counter):
      yield i
  if tree[v * 2 + 1]:
    for i in traverse(tree, v * 2 + 1, c + 1, r, counter):
      yield i

length = int(sys.argv[1])
arr = [int(random.random() > 0.99) for i in xrange(length)]
tree = [0] * length * 4
build(arr, tree, 1, 0, len(arr) - 1)
slow = [i for (i, e) in enumerate(arr) if e == 1]
counter = [0]
fast = [i for i in traverse(tree, 1, 0, len(arr) - 1, counter)]
assert(slow == fast)
print "Total number:", len(arr)
print "Number of non-deleted:", sum(arr)
print "Number of visited nodes:", counter[0]
```

Тут мы "удаляем" 99% элементов и строим список индексов неудаленных. В первом случае (slow), мы просто пробегаемся по всему массиву длиной length (1000000), и выводим индексы ненулевых элементов. Во втором случае (fast) мы обходим дерево. Результаты для разных length следующие:

```
Total number: 10000
Number of non-deleted: 103
Number of visited nodes: 802

Total number: 100000
Number of non-deleted: 1021
Number of visited nodes: 8016

Total number: 1000000
Number of non-deleted: 10060
Number of visited nodes: 78413

Total number: 10000000
Number of non-deleted: 99706
Number of visited nodes: 783587
```

Как видим сложность обхода вроде бы линейная, для полной уверенности нужно еще поварьировать процент удаленных узлов, но мне лень.

Хотя алгоритм и имеет меньшую сложность, не факт, что его стоит применять вообще. Как уже ниже заметили, в реальной жизни в алгоритмах на матрицах большую роль играет локальность чтения данных.  Поэтому для строк такой "ускоренный" обход имеет смысл применять только в случае когда большая часть элементов удалена (тут надо эксперементировать, чтобы найти точные критерии).

Comment: А можно ли использовать какую-то модификацию с целью ускорения итерации?
Я из каких соображений спрашиваю: если мы потом хотим делать какие-то преобразования с матрицей нам бы желательна быстрая итерация по строкам\столбцам.

Comment: @miramentis, обновил ответ. Про итерации по столбцам: если хотите добиться скорости, лучше никогда их не применяйте. Обход по столбцам на порядок медленнее, чем обход по строкам. Это происходит из-за промахоы по кэшу. По ссылке можно почитать подробнее http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~cs151/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch14s04.html .

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [boost.multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html)